# Using 'GoTo' command in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I read that using the `Goto` command is very bad and can mess up your code. I also read that there was a poll saying that 40% of Delphi developers will be very cross if they see the `goto` command and delphi together and the other 40% don't even know of the `goto` command, why is that?

But anyways, I was making a program that checks if you qualify for a bursary by getting the two marks and getting the avarage of those two marks. In order to get the Bursary, you need to have a 90% average or above and it will display your average in a label and if you qualify in another label. I recently also learned about the `If` command and now I am just busy playing around with it.

Here's my code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iMaths, iScience, iAvarage   :   integer;

begin
  iScience := sedScience.value;
  iMaths   := sedMath.value;
  iAvarage := round((iMaths+iScience)/2);

  if iMaths = 0
    then
      begin
      showmessage ('Sorry, please put a propper value in the Maths and Science box!');
    end;

    if iAvarage >= 90
     then
        begin
          lblAvarage.caption := 'Your avarage is: ' + IntToStr (iAvarage);
          lblOutput.caption := 'You qualify for an Einstein Bursary!';
        end
    else
        begin
          lblAvarage.Caption := 'Your avarage is ' + IntToStr (iAvarage);
          lblOutput.caption := 'Sorry, you do not qualify for an Einstein bursary.';
        end;
end;
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    sedMath.value := 0;
    sedScience.value := 0;
    lblAvarage.caption := ' ';
    lblOutput.caption := ' ';
    sedMath.setfocus
  end;

end.
```

Where I say `if iMaths = 0` thats just making sure that there is a value in the SpinEdit, if there isn't, it must restart at the ButtonClick handler with a message saying `Please insert a proper value`. That all works fine, but it still displays the average in the labels (lblOutput and lblAvarage) which I don't want it to do!

If I use the `goto` command, this is how I think it should look:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iMaths, iScience, iAvarage   :   integer;
label
  lRestart;
begin
  lRestart;
  iScience := sedScience.value;
  iMaths   := sedMath.value;
  iAvarage := round((iMaths+iScience)/2);

  if iMaths and iScience = 0
    then
      begin
      showmessage ('Sorry, please put a propper value in the Maths and Science box!');
      goto lRestart;
    end;
```

(BTW, I know the above code it wrong, I tried!)

I googled `goto` but I find things that are different to what I need.

Any help or advice on how to use the `goto` command would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not related to your question, but "40%" and "the other 40%"?

Comment: Your `label` version would bring you into an infinite loop, because the user wouldn't have any chance to update the component values. What you want is to `Exit` the event method, let the user fix the values and press the button again.

Comment: So the goto command wont work in this scenario? If so, is there a replacement?

Comment: Goto is no necesary if you encapsulate your logic in functions and call them instead of jumping around with goto statements

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Exit&ExpandCode1=Yes

Comment: @hvd "in Delphi" poll, it seems 40% of Delphi developers do not even know Goto exists in Delphi. Another 40% would have a very low opinion on you if they would see Goto in your Delphi code." [link](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/goto_label.htm)

Comment: @AlexK., please do not disclose an existence of that website to the beginner.

Comment: @link Heh, "another 40%" and "the other 40%" don't mean the same thing. :) "Another 40%" sounds right and accounts for the remaining 20% who know `goto` exists and think that there are some cases where it may be useful.

Comment: What percentage think it is a very bad idea AND don't know it exists ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct for `goto`. It should be:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
....
label
  lRestart;
begin
lRestart:
  ....
  goto lRestart;
  ....
end;
```

But if you ever wanted to do something like this you'd surely avoid the `goto` by writing it thus:

```
repeat
  // do something
until OkToContinue;
```

---

That said, your code should be:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iMaths, iScience, iAverage: integer;
begin
  iScience := sedScience.value;
  iMaths   := sedMath.value;
  iAverage := round((iMaths+iScience)/2);

  if (iMaths=0) or (iScience=0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Sorry, please put a propper value in the Maths and Science box!');
    exit;
  end;

  // do the calculation
end;
```

There's no need for looping or `goto` in your event handler. You have to exit when you find an error and give the user opportunity to fix the mistake and click the button again. So it's just a complete mis-think on your part that you would need a `goto`.

I guess you have not yet fully grasped the concept of event driven programming. Were you to go back to the beginning instead of exiting the procedure, the user would have no opportunity to modify the values of the spin edit controls and you would show the message again and again and again. Try it and see what I mean.

Note also that I fixed a number of other errors in your code.

---

As for `goto`, I'm sure that you won't need it ever. I've only ever found `goto` to be useful in languages that don't support structured exceptions. Delphi does not fall into that camp.

Comment: Jumping out of a nested IF block with goto is afaik still faster.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Not measurably if the user has to click on a dialog box before the jump happens.

Comment: Thanks David! Your a real help to noobs at coding like me!

Comment: It's certainly not for this case. It is more CPU intensive code ( codecs, (de)compression, encryption) and language helpers.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort In most cases, it is not, since a `break` is implemented as a `jz ...` assembler opcode. Just like `goto`.

Comment: break/continue operate on loops, not nested if blocks.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Yes, this is what I already emphasized in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to use `goto` in your programs.

Some reasons not to use it, since in most cases:

- It will make your code less readable;
- It can be easily converted into nested `repeat .. until` or `while ..` structures, which are usually with the same exact timing (will be compiled as assembler `jmp ..` opcode.

Sometimes, it may be slightly faster to put the *conditional expression* of the `repeat .. until` or `while ..` structures *within the loop*, and use `break` and `continue` and `repeat .. until false` or `while true do ..`:

```
function GotoEndOfJSONString(P: PUTF8Char): PUTF8Char;
begin // P^='"' at function call
  inc(P);
  repeat
    if P^=#0 then
      break else
    if P^<>'\' then
      if P^<>'"' then
        inc(P) else
        break else
      inc(P,2);
  until false;
  result := P;
end; // P^='"' at function return
```

Which will be compiled with very optimized assembler:

```
    inc eax
@s: mov dl,[eax]
    test dl,dl
    jz @e
    cmp dl,$5c
    je @2
    cmp dl,$22
    je @e
    inc eax
    jmp @s
@2: add eax,2
    jmp @s
@e: ret
```

But this is perhaps worth it only for very low-level code, and will make it less readable. Writing such code is very close to writing directly the assembler code: you know that the `break` and `continue` will be converted into direct `jmp ..` assembler opcodes.

The only case when I use `goto` is in some well-defined conditions:

- Identified low-level process of data (e.g. text handling);
- Only for performance reasons;
- With proper unit testing (since code is less readable);
- When branching is needed in-between `case .. of` inner blocks, or from one loop to another;
- When I want to avoid calling a sub-procedure in older versions of Delphi (e.g. Delphi 7) - but in modern Delphi, `goto` can be replaced by an `inline` local procedure.

Some example:

```
procedure TTextWriter.AddJSONEscape(P: Pointer; Len: PtrInt);
var c: PtrUInt;
label Esc, nxt;
begin
  if P=nil then exit;
  if Len=0 then
    Len := MaxInt;
  if B>=BEnd then
    Flush;
  repeat
    inc(B);
    // escape chars, according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt
    c := PByte(P)^;
    if c>=32 then begin
      if c in [ord('\'),{ord('/'),}ord('"')] then goto Esc;
      B^ := AnsiChar(c);
nxt:  if Len=1 then
        break;
      dec(Len);
      inc(PByte(P));
      if B<BEnd then
        continue;
      Flush;
    end else
    case c of
    0: begin
      dec(B); break; end;
    8: begin
      c := ord('b'); goto Esc; end;
    9: begin
      c := ord('t'); goto Esc; end;
    $a: begin
      c := ord('n'); goto Esc; end;
    $c: begin
      c := ord('f'); goto Esc; end;
    $d: begin
      c := ord('r');
Esc:  B^ := '\';
      if B>=BEnd then  // inlined: avoid endless loop
        Flush;
      B[1] := AnsiChar(c);
      inc(B);
      goto nxt;
    end;
    else begin // characters below ' ', #7 e.g. -> // 'u0007'
      B^ := '\';
      AddShort('u00');
      Add(HexChars[c shr 4],HexChars[c and $F]);
      goto nxt;
    end;
    end;
  until false;
end;
```

As a conclusion, outside the *FastCode challenge* in pure pascal or some low-level code, you should not see any `goto` any more.

Comment: The optimizer example is convoluted IMHO, using a loop to abuse break might wreak havoc with the codegenerator/optimizer in more complex function. And only allowable without exceptions is what I already say. I don't believe in forbidding anything that is in half the components a beginning user might download from the web. The same as with assembler that provokes similar reactions.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort This is exactly my point: do not use `goto`, and even not use `break` within such endless loop, unless you may have written the code in assembler, due to performance low-level expectation! So both practice are not to be used in general high-level code.